# OPENSSL Convert binary bytes to SHA256 C++

Tags: c++, openssl, checksum, sha256

I'm basically trying to get a checksum for my mnemonic words.
I have the binary bytes and want to convert them to sha256 to get the first 4 bits and validate it.

Took me about 2 days to realize that hashing is different from a text string to sha256 than bytes to sha256.
The below function works but it hashes as strings not as bytes.

```
string sha256(const string str)
{
    unsigned char hash[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    SHA256_CTX sha256;
    SHA256_Init(&sha256);
    SHA256_Update(&sha256, str.c_str(), str.size());
    SHA256_Final(hash, &sha256);
    stringstream ss;
    for(int i = 0; i < SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        ss << hex << setw(2) << setfill('0') << (int)hash[i];
    }
    return ss.str();
}
```

I'm new to openssl and wasn't able to find any solutions online.
If someone could adapt my function to hash the binary bytes input correctly I would really appreciate it. 
Thanks.

To clarify here's an example:
10111110011001010101110111001111010100011111011010110001110101111011110111000101101001100011110100010100011101000011011011100000

this used as text gives me this hash:
2d7ffa3c8f9c3fc043045f2564101eabf80bcdb983d1d560b6b93f52ea824942

and used as bytes give me this correct hash:
5e5c92432e692f803539715bb624cd2e35b5b491c6bc67aee87ae82600dedf12

I used this website to hash: https://cryptii.com/hash-function

Comment: "Took me about 2 days to realize that hashing is different from a text string to sha256 than bytes to sha256." What do you mean? Hashing always hashes bytes, it doesn't know anything about text at all.

Comment: I might be wrong but, if you add the same binary string as text, and as bytes you get different results: https://cryptii.com/hash-function

Comment: Unclear exactly what you are asking - please clarify

Comment: 10111110011001010101110111001111010100011111011010110001110101111011110111000101101001100011110100010100011101000011011011100000

this used as text gives me this hash:
2d7ffa3c8f9c3fc043045f2564101eabf80bcdb983d1d560b6b93f52ea824942

and used as bytes give me this correct hash:
5e5c92432e692f803539715bb624cd2e35b5b491c6bc67aee87ae82600dedf12

Comment: @CsgoTalksCom please do not add details in the comments, instead add/clarify your original post.

Comment: Interpreting a sequence of bits as ascii text will obviously give you a different result than interpreting them as bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems you need to interpret your input as a **stream of bits**. Group them into bytes and off you go:

```
unsigned char hash[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
SHA256_CTX sha256;
SHA256_Init(&sha256);
uint8_t str[] = { 0b10111110, 0b01100101, 0b01011101, 0b11001111, 0b01010001, 0b11110110, 0b10110001, 0b11010111, 0b10111101, 0b11000101, 0b10100110, 0b00111101, 0b00010100, 0b01110100, 0b00110110, 0b11100000 };
SHA256_Update(&sha256, str, sizeof(str));
SHA256_Final(hash, &sha256);
```

Hash output:

```
5e5c92432e692f803539715bb624cd2e35b5b491c6bc67aee87ae82600dedf12
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f2b8ccff6b12d07e)

Comment: any idea how can I get my vector of strings into uint8_t?

Comment: What vector? That might be a whole new question in itself.

Comment: right now I have the stream of bits in a string vector: 0b10111110, 0b01100101, 0b01011101.. is it possible to get them into the uint8?
sadly it most likely is another question/problem.

Comment: How I'm may convert bitset to uint8_t. Help me please, 4 days lost)